# firebase query not able to fetch the data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to query firebase DB and expecting multiple outputs

JSON file :

```
 [ {
  "NAME" : "R",
  "No" : "5"
}, {
  "NAME" : "R",
  "No" : "8"
}, {
  "NAME" : "C",
  "No" : "12"
}, {
  "NAME" : "D",
  "No" : "15"
}, {
  "NAME" : "E",
  "No" : "19"
}, {
  "NAME" : "P",
  "No" : "22"
} ]
```

My expectation is when I query for NAME "R" I must get out put of "5" "8".. this my JS code I am getting only 1 out put of "5" always.

Following is code. Is every thing ok with this?

```js
function getdetails_SITEINFO() {
  // body...

var input = document.getElementById("site_id").value;
var input_final = input.toUpperCase();

//var database_SITEINFO = firebase.database("https://swite-76bd2.firebaseio.com");



var ref = firebase.database().ref('/').orderByChild("NAME").equalTo(input_final)
ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot)
{


var obj = JSON.stringify(snapshot.val());
var str = obj.replace (/"/g ,"").replace (/:/g, " <==> ").replace (/{/g, "").replace(/}/g, "").replace(/,/g, "\n").replace(/]/g, "");
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =  str ;

},);
}
```

Comment: I'm thinking that because you're setting the innerHTML, you're only seeing the final value displayed on screen.... and that `child_added` IS actually firing twice like you'd expect - you just don't see it happening. Throw a `console.log(snapshot.val())` before your `var obj = JSON...` assignment, and I suspect that you'll see two console logs, one with each value.

Comment: @JeremyW your are right on the console.log I am getting each value .. how do I fix this in the innerHTML ?